# Converting a 2d array into a 1d array

Tags: java, arrays

just curious on how to convert a 2d array into a 1d array.

```
For example if my array was:

int[][] arr = {{2,3,4},
               {5,6,7}};

lets say I wanted it just to be transferred to a 1d array such as:

int[] arr = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

Comment: Well, first off, you start writing some code that attempts to do it. If you get stuck, then you have something to ask a specific question about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you can create a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of `int[]` instances; then [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) that to an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) before converting it to an array. Which will do exactly as you describe. Like,

```
int[][] arr = { { 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7 } };
int[] b = Stream.of(arr).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Which outputs

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 and integer array you can use:

```
int[][] arr2d = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, {6, 7} };
int[] arr1d = Arrays.stream(arr2d).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

For Java 7 or object array:

```
Object[][] obj2d = new Object[][] {};

List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] arr : obj2d) {
    for (Object obj : arr) {
        list.add(obj);
    }
}

Object[] obj1d = list.toArray(new Object[] {});
```